# Visualize vector graphics in Java, which library?

Tags: zooming, vector-graphics, java

I need to visualize a large vector graphic. It's a map of roads, the roads are just lines. Is there a library for that? It would be nice if that library had support for zoom-in/zoom-out and would be easy to extend. E.g. to implement selection of roads or some nice mouse-over effects. The licence should permit usage in a commercial project.

Thanks, Philip

Edit: Is there a reason not to go with Graphics2D or SWT Graphics? (The project is on SWT and doesn't involve any SVGs.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Batik](http://xml.apache.org/batik/)

> Batik is a Java-based toolkit for
>   applications or applets that want to
>   use images in the Scalable Vector
>   Graphics (SVG) format for various
>   purposes, such as display, generation
>   or manipulation. Another possibility
>   is to use Batik’s modules to convert
>   SVG to various formats, such as raster
>   images (JPEG, PNG or TIFF) or other
>   vector formats (EPS or PDF, the latter
>   two due to the transcoders provided by
>   Apache FOP). The latest revision of
>   Batik, release 1.7, is a conformant
>   static SVG implementation and supports
>   interactivity, linking and scripting
>   features of the SVG specification.

Another good alternatives are [FreeHEP](http://java.freehep.org/vectorgraphics/) and [VectorGraphics2D](http://trac.erichseifert.de/vectorgraphics2d/)

Comment: Batik is no option as far as I can see it be it must be possible to implement selections of objects. For that I would have to implement some mapping between the SVG and the data source, I think this would be over-kill. FreeHEP is a Graphics2D->SVG-Exporter, VectorGraphics2D seems to have no nice graphics. :S

Comment: You can use AsSvg() from SpatiaLite or SVG generator from Batik distribution as alternative to over-kill.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about SVG-like graphics, i think [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is the way.

Comment: Yeah I also stumbled over Batik, but I am not using SVG in that project.

Comment: SQLite/SpatiaLite, SHP or an internal binary format. (Though the data might be processed by the JTS library.) Of course there is existing GIS software but this is over-kill, and there are licence problems.

Comment: @Philip i suggest you ask the question to StackOverflow, as you are not displaying simple vector graphics, but inf act cartographic data, which is quite a different problem.